# Overwriting a text file

Tags: java

So im trying to edit a line in my file and im following this steps:
 1.first i copy lines that i dont want to edit in e new text file
 2.then i modify the line i want and write it in the text file
 3.here i have problems deleting the first file and renaming my temp file as the  first
So this is what i have done:

```
public void edit(String a) throws FileNotFoundException{
    output=new Formatter("temp.txt");
    try
    {
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String d= input.next();
            if(d.equals(a)){
                output.format("%s %s\n", d,"edited");
            }
            else{
                output.format("%s\n ",d);

            }

        }
        output.close();
        File realname= new File("shembull.txt");    
        realname.delete(); 
        new File("temp.txt").renameTo(realname); 

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.printf("\n%s", "Err");
    }
```

The problem that im having is that the temp file is created and it has inside what i want it to have but when i try to rename it and delete the first file nothing hapens, the files remain the same.
Hope anyone helps me...thanks :)

Comment: why instead of renaming the file just overwrite the contents

Comment: what way do u suggest for overwriting the contents?

Comment: test whether `realname.canWrite()` evaluates to true or false at the point where you try to delete it - if false, it might be that your Java program doesn't have the permission to delete the file

Comment: i get true as a response of this method

Comment: You don't give many hints as to what input is, which makes it hard to duplicate your issue. It is possible that the problem is that input is still open when you try to rename the temp file.

Comment: yes i forgot to close input so thanks :D